# In Nmap: can we specify the --version-intensity option with A option?

Tags: nmap

After having read Nmap documentation (in french but the translation seems pretty accurate), a question arose:

Is it possible to use **--version-intensity** option (from the **-sV** option) when using the **-A** option ?

I'm asking because **-A** option integrates *service/version* detection (which correspond to the **-sV** option right ?) but in the documentation of **-A** option I can't see any reference to the **--version-intensity** option.

I hope I was clear in my explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Under the hood, `-A` is simply an alias for a number of other flags, including `-sV` which enables version scanning. User-specified control arguments are given precedence over defaults (if any) set by such flags.

As an example, `-T4` sets a timing template including `--max-rtt-timeout 1250ms`, `--initial-rtt-timeout 500ms`, and `--max-retries 6`. However, you can manually specify any of these in addition to the `-T4` flag to override these defaults.

Comment: So, just to be clear: **nmap -A  --version-intensity 9 10.11.11.54** would work ?

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine.